# Cisco ASA 5510 odd interface issue

Tags: cisco-asa

Cisco ASA 5510 running Version 8.0(5)
Two routers on separate ports. One works as it should, the other is being finnicky for a completely unknown reason.

```
ping PORT1 8.8.8.8
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 8.8.8.8, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 10/10/10 ms

ping PORT2 8.8.8.8
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 8.8.8.8, timeout is 2 seconds:
??!!! / ?!!!? / !!!??
Success rate is 60 percent (3/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 20/30/50 ms
```

It’s always 3/5 but different patterns as shown above.
So I figure one of two things could be happening. Either the router behind PORT2 is bad or the cable is bad. So I hooked up a laptop using the same cable and gave it the same IP. It works just fine. No drops, latencies, or anything else.

Could it possibly be the actual port on the ASA? Should I try a different port? Haven’t tried that yet because I find that unlikely. Or could it be the config? Not sure what config sections to post, so please let me know. Both ports are configured exactly the same and I’m not aware of a config that would only let 3 out of 5 packets through. The MTU is the same on both at 1500.

Comment: If you ping the next hop on PORT2, does it give the same 3/5 issue?

Comment: No, the next hop, the actual ISP router does not return any pings. 0/5. Google return 3/5 but the actual ISP router does nothing. Even though if I connect a computer to it and give it the same IP, it does 5/5. I am totally confused.

Comment: Scratch that. I'm now getting 5/5 from the next hop local ISP router, quickly. It's fully functioning as expected. But Google is still only 2 or 3 out of 5 from the ASA even though it works just fine from a computer with the same static IP and cable.

Comment: Do a tracert for `8.8.8.8` and see what the hops in between return. You can try extended ping tests to them to see if you can figure out where the issue may be.

Answer (score -1):

You can find further information about issues related to Cisco ASA 5510 in the following link: http://cs.co/90078gwBF

Also, you can open a “Discussion” at the Cisco Support Forums on the firewalling sub-community: https://supportforums.cisco.com/community/5966/firewalling 
So and expert on this matter can assist you to solve this issue.

We hope this information is helpful

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault. Please consider [the tour](https://serverfault.com/tour). See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Answers for this site should stand alone. Referring to a link should only be used as reference to support. Pointing to ask elsewhere is not answering the question.

Comment: The first link is a very generic ASA documentation which I don't need since my device is fully configured and I just have a specific problem. And I already posted the question on the Cisco forum: https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/13289596/asa-5510-interface-issue